# SQL statistics system table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, statistics

I have created a statistics in a table using SQL SERVER 2008 . In which system table this information is getting stored (Just like all the table info are stored in in sys.tables)...?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Please review it to see how you can make it more clear what you seek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sys.stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177623.aspx)?